# Adwhirl Layout issue

Tags: android, layout, adwhirl

I am currently using `admob` for a couple of my apps.  This seems to work well, except the fill rates can get down to as low as 78%.  So I decided to signup for `AdWhirl`.

So, I followed the instructions, what they are, on the setup instructions page for `AdWhirl`, but can not get anything to work.  I either wind up with code that throws no errors and does not work, or if I add `<AdWhirlLayout>` to my `xml` the app will not run at all.

Can someone please explain to me what I need to do to get this working?

It appears there are some steps that are assumed and not explained.

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or a handset?  I've found some ad networks are very sensitive about host names/IPs (they like requests from a carrier's network vs. some internal network IP address) and especially user agent.

Comment: emulator and handset.  I have tried both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this very helpful in getting AdWhirl up and running.  The emulator is still very fickle in displaying the adds... watch the LogCat to try and decipher what is happening with AdWhirl, but first go to this link and follow instructions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898838/howto-implement-adwhirl-in-an-android-project

Oh, and it takes some time before the ads actually display (for me I had to wait overnight after implementing) for my key to work and serve up ads.

Comment: Well, blame it on stackoverflow, as the link was to another question that was answered on here.  I didn't figure they would remove their own content.